# Selenium WebDriver how to close browser confirmation popup with OK and Cancel button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing tests for a web App using selenium webDriver and came across a scenario where when I try to delete a link the browser I get a popup saying:

> Delete : "dummyname" Are you sure?

The browser page is asking you to confirm that you want to delete data, with 2 buttons: `OK` and `cancel`.

How do I click on those buttons?

Comment: Can you post the html code for that popup? and Which language are you using? Java?

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Comment: Yes I am using java for scripting

Answer (score 0):

For ok

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

For cancel

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: driver.switchTo().alert(); use this , it will pass your control on pop-up and find the ok button element and perform click event on it .. Then use driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); to switch back on main page

Comment: If it is still not work then please share the HTML code

Comment: Some pop up messages are not standart html alert message. it is possible to be a user defined pop up.(i had several such that in projects). you should select OK or Yes(or whatever it is caleld) via selectors. Check that is there any html code for that pop up.

Comment: you are absolute right @Mahsum Akbas that why I asked for the HTML code... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should throw something like this in your BasePage.java and call acceptAlert() or dismissAlert(), but the magic lies in the code as Shubham Jain described above.

```
protected void acceptAlert() {
    waitFor(new BooleanCondition() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            try {
                webDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                return true;
            } catch (WebDriverException ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public String describeFailure() {
            return COULD_NOT_LOCATE_OR_ACCEPT_ALERT_BOX;
        }
    });
}

protected void dismissAlert() {
    waitFor(new BooleanCondition() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver) {
            try {
                webDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
                return true;
            } catch (WebDriverException ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public String describeFailure() {
            return COULD_NOT_LOCATE_OR_ACCEPT_ALERT_BOX;
        }
    });
}
```